# Chrome Shape Detection API: Get tilt of face

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Chrome has a Shape Detection API and one of the features is to detect Faces from an image or camera feed.

The API returns the location of both eyes mouth and nose and returns a boundingBox for where the face is. Is there a way to determine if a face is tilted on the left side, right side or up?

The thing that confuses is me that Chrome considers the background too for the position of the bounding box and so it returns where the face is in the image.